# Post HTTP call working on postman but not on local in Java

Tags: java, http, jaxb, postman

I am calling an api the purpose of which to validate customer's data which is working fine in postman but in my local while doing http call it's giving a different response and not passing even the first line. The request and response are in the form of XML.

Postman request and response are as follows:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://ckyc.olacabs-dev.in:54322/crmapi/TrackwizzWebApi/A63/CreateUpdateCustomer/V1' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CustomerRelatedPartyCreateUpdateRequest>
    <ParentCompany>NFPL</ParentCompany>
    <ApiToken>ecef5041-a08a-43c9-9599-fc2d0c8da616</ApiToken>
    <RecordRequestDetails>
        <RecordRequestDetail>
            <SourceSystemName>HomeLoan</SourceSystemName>
            <SourceSystemCustomerCode>321875112</SourceSystemCustomerCode>
            <IsSmallCustomer>0</IsSmallCustomer>
            <EkycOTPBased>0</EkycOTPBased>
            <CustomerStatus>
                <StatusDetail>
                    <Status>Active</Status>
                    <EffectiveDate>1970-01-01T05:29:57.991+05:30</EffectiveDate>
                </StatusDetail>
            </CustomerStatus>
            <CustomerType>1</CustomerType>
            <Prefix>MISS</Prefix>
            <FirstName>dolly</FirstName>
            <LastName>vaishnav</LastName>
            <FatherPrefix>MR</FatherPrefix>
            <fatherFirstName>Prakash</fatherFirstName>
            <Gender>female</Gender>
            <formSixty>0</formSixty>
            <KYCAttestationType>1</KYCAttestationType>
            <CountryOfResidence>IN</CountryOfResidence>
            <DateofBirth>1970-01-01T05:29:57.991+05:30</DateofBirth>
            <KYCDateOfDeclaration>1970-01-01T05:29:57.991+05:30</KYCDateOfDeclaration>
            <KYCPlaceOfDeclaration>Mumbai</KYCPlaceOfDeclaration>
            <KYCVerificationDate>1970-01-01T05:29:57.991+05:30</KYCVerificationDate>
            <KYCEmployeeName>Vikash</KYCEmployeeName>
            <KYCEmployeeDesignation>manager</KYCEmployeeDesignation>
            <KYCVerificationBranch>mumbai</KYCVerificationBranch>
            <KYCEmployeeCode>1234</KYCEmployeeCode>
            <AddressDetails>
                <AddressDetail>
                    <AddressType>permanent</AddressType>
                    <AddressLine1>xyz</AddressLine1>
                    <PinCode>491001</PinCode>
                    <City>bhilai</City>
                    <AddressLine2>kormangala</AddressLine2>
                    <AddressLine3>5th block</AddressLine3>
                    <State>CG</State>
                    <Country>IN</Country>
                    <District>durg</District>
                </AddressDetail>
            </AddressDetails>
            <PermanentAddressProof>passport</PermanentAddressProof>
            <CorrespondenceAddressProof>dl</CorrespondenceAddressProof>
            <IdentificationDetails>
                <IdentificationDetail>
                    <IdType>passport</IdType>
                    <IdNumber>AVPBV4738</IdNumber>
                </IdentificationDetail>
            </IdentificationDetails>
            <Minor>0</Minor>
            <ModuleApplicable>
                <ModuleDetail>
                    <Module>ckyc</Module>
                </ModuleDetail>
            </ModuleApplicable>
        </RecordRequestDetail>
    </RecordRequestDetails>
</CustomerRelatedPartyCreateUpdateRequest>
'
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<A63CustomerResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ApiToken>ecef5041-a08a-43c9-9599-fc2d0c8da616</ApiToken>
    <RequestId>82718d83-9206-4ab1-819a-a79e63e832a4</RequestId>
    <RequestStatus>AcceptedbyTW</RequestStatus>
    <ParentCompany>NFPL</ParentCompany>
    <CustomerResponseDetails>
        <A63CustomerResponseDetail>
            <TransactionId xsi:nil="true" />
            <SourceSystemName>HomeLoan</SourceSystemName>
            <SourceSystemCustomerCode>321875112</SourceSystemCustomerCode>
            <CustomerIntegrationStatusCode>AcceptedbyTW</CustomerIntegrationStatusCode>
            <TrackWizzUpdatedOn>22-02-2022</TrackWizzUpdatedOn>
        </A63CustomerResponseDetail>
    </CustomerResponseDetails>
</A63CustomerResponse>
```

Sample java code:

```
public Map<String, String> updateCustomerData(String userId, CkycCustomerDetailsUpdateRequest request) throws CkycException {

        String addressType = request.getAddressType();
        String addressLine1 = request.getAddressLine1();
        String addressLine2 = request.getAddressLine2();
        String addressLine3 = request.getAddressLine3();
        int pincode = request.getPincode();
        String city = request.getCity();
        String state = request.getState();
        String country = request.getCountry();
        String district = request.getDistrict();

        AddressDetail addressDetail = formPayloadForAddressDetail(addressType, addressLine1, addressLine2, addressLine3, pincode, city, state, country, district);
        List<AddressDetail> addressDetailList = new ArrayList<>();
        addressDetailList.add(addressDetail);

        AddressDetails addressDetails = new AddressDetails();
        addressDetails.setAddressDetail(addressDetailList);

        String idType = request.getIdType();
        String idNumber = request.getIdNumber();

        IdentificationDetail identificationDetail = formPayloadForIdentificationDetail(idType, idNumber);

        IdentificationDetails identificationDetails = new IdentificationDetails();
        identificationDetails.setIdentificationDetail(identificationDetail);

        String module = request.getModule();
        ModuleDetail moduleDetail = new ModuleDetail();
        moduleDetail.setModule(module);

        ModuleApplicable moduleApplicable = new ModuleApplicable();
        moduleApplicable.setModuleDetail(moduleDetail);

        String status = request.getStatus();
        Date effectiveDate = request.getEffectiveDate();

        CustomerStatus customerStatus = formPayloadForCustomerStatus(status, effectiveDate);

        String prefix = request.getPrefix();
        String firstName = request.getFirstName();
        String lastName = request.getLastName();
        String fatherPrefix = request.getFatherPrefix();
        String fatherFirstName = request.getFatherFirstName();
        String gender = request.getGender();
        String sourceSystemName = request.getSourceSystemName();
        String sourceSystemCustomerCode = request.getSourceSystemCustomerCode();
        int isSmallCustomer = request.getIsSmallCustomer();
        int ekycOTPBased = request.getEkycOTPBased();
        String customerType = request.getCustomerType();
        int formSixty = request.getFormSixty();
        int kycAttestationType = request.getKYCAttestationType();
        String countryOfResidence = request.getCountryOfResidence();
        Date dob = request.getDob();
        Date kycDateOfDeclaration = request.getKycDateOfDeclaration();
        String kycPlaceOfDeclaration = request.getKycPlaceOfDeclaration();
        Date kycVerificationDate = request.getKycVerificationDate();
        String kycEmployeeName = request.getKycEmployeeName();
        String kycEmployeeDesignation = request.getKycEmployeeDesignation();
        String kycVerificationBranch = request.getKycVerificationBranch();
        String kycEmployeeCode = request.getKycEmployeeCode();
        String permanentAddressProof = request.getPermanentAddressProof();
        String correspondenceAddressProof = request.getCorrespondenceAddressProof();
        int minor = request.getMinor();


        RecordRequestDetails recordRequestDetails = formPayloadForRecordRequestDetails(prefix, firstName, lastName, fatherFirstName, fatherPrefix, gender, sourceSystemCustomerCode, sourceSystemName,
                isSmallCustomer, ekycOTPBased, customerType, formSixty, countryOfResidence, dob, kycAttestationType, kycDateOfDeclaration, kycPlaceOfDeclaration,
                kycVerificationBranch, kycVerificationDate, kycEmployeeName, kycEmployeeDesignation, kycEmployeeCode, permanentAddressProof, correspondenceAddressProof, minor,
                customerStatus, identificationDetails, moduleApplicable, addressDetails);

        String parentCompany = request.getParentCompany();
        String apiToken = request.getApiToken();

        A63CustomerDetailsUpdateRequest a63CustomerDetailsUpdateRequest = formPayloadForCustomerDetailsUpdateReqest(parentCompany, apiToken, recordRequestDetails);
        String payloadCustomerUpdateDetailsXml = XMLUtil.toXML(a63CustomerDetailsUpdateRequest);
        String response = null;
        response = doPostCkycReverseUpload(userId, payloadCustomerUpdateDetailsXml, trackwizzConfig.getImageIntegrationEndPoint(), 0, CKYC_UPLOAD, CUSTOMER_VALIDATION_API);

        JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(response, true);
        String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();

        try {
            return mapper.readValue(jsonString, Map.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new CkycException(ErrorCode.internal_parsing_error, "Unable to parse the response");
        }
    }

    private A63CustomerDetailsUpdateRequest formPayloadForCustomerDetailsUpdateReqest(String parentCompany, String apiToken, RecordRequestDetails recordRequestDetails) {
        A63CustomerDetailsUpdateRequest a63CustomerDetailsUpdateRequest = new A63CustomerDetailsUpdateRequest();
        a63CustomerDetailsUpdateRequest.setParentCompany(parentCompany);
        a63CustomerDetailsUpdateRequest.setApiToken(apiToken);
        a63CustomerDetailsUpdateRequest.setRecordRequestDetails(recordRequestDetails);
        return a63CustomerDetailsUpdateRequest;
    }

    private RecordRequestDetails formPayloadForRecordRequestDetails(String prefix, String firstName, String lastName, String fatherFirstName, String fatherPrefix, String gender, String sourceSystemCustomerCode, String sourceSystemName, int isSmallCustomer, int ekycOTPBased, String customerType, int formSixty, String countryOfResidence, Date dob, int kycAttestationType, Date kycDateOfDeclaration, String kycPlaceOfDeclaration, String kycVerificationBranch, Date kycVerificationDate, String kycEmployeeName, String kycEmployeeDesignation, String kycEmployeeCode, String permanentAddressProof, String correspondenceAddressProof, int minor, CustomerStatus customerStatus, IdentificationDetails identificationDetails, ModuleApplicable moduleApplicable, AddressDetails addressDetails) {
        RecordRequestDetail recordRequestDetail = new RecordRequestDetail();
        recordRequestDetail.setPrefix(prefix);
        recordRequestDetail.setFirstName(firstName);
        recordRequestDetail.setLastName(lastName);
        recordRequestDetail.setFatherPrefix(fatherPrefix);
        recordRequestDetail.setFatherFirstName(fatherFirstName);
        recordRequestDetail.setGender(gender);
        recordRequestDetail.setSourceSystemName(sourceSystemName);
        recordRequestDetail.setSourceSystemCustomerCode(sourceSystemCustomerCode);
        recordRequestDetail.setIsSmallCustomer(isSmallCustomer);
        recordRequestDetail.setEkycOTPBased(ekycOTPBased);
        recordRequestDetail.setCustomerType(customerType);
        recordRequestDetail.setCustomerStatus(customerStatus);
        recordRequestDetail.setFormSixty(formSixty);
        recordRequestDetail.setDob(dob);
        recordRequestDetail.setMinor(minor);
        recordRequestDetail.setCountryOfResidence(countryOfResidence);
        recordRequestDetail.setKycAttestationType(kycAttestationType);
        recordRequestDetail.setKycDateOfDeclaration(kycDateOfDeclaration);
        recordRequestDetail.setKycEmployeeCode(kycEmployeeCode);
        recordRequestDetail.setKycEmployeeName(kycEmployeeName);
        recordRequestDetail.setKycPlaceOfDeclaration(kycPlaceOfDeclaration);
        recordRequestDetail.setKycVerificationBranch(kycVerificationBranch);
        recordRequestDetail.setKycVerificationDate(kycVerificationDate);
        recordRequestDetail.setKycEmployeeDesignation(kycEmployeeDesignation);
        recordRequestDetail.setPermanentAddressProof(permanentAddressProof);
        recordRequestDetail.setCorrespondenceAddressProof(correspondenceAddressProof);
        recordRequestDetail.setIdentificationDetails(identificationDetails);
        recordRequestDetail.setModuleApplicable(moduleApplicable);
        recordRequestDetail.setAddressDetails(addressDetails);
        RecordRequestDetails recordRequestDetails = new RecordRequestDetails();
        recordRequestDetails.setRecordRequestDetail(recordRequestDetail);
        return recordRequestDetails;
    }

    private CustomerStatus formPayloadForCustomerStatus(String status, Date effectiveDate) {
        StatusDetail statusDetail = new StatusDetail();
        statusDetail.setStatus(status);
        statusDetail.setEffectiveDate(effectiveDate);
        CustomerStatus customerStatus = new CustomerStatus();
        customerStatus.setStatusDetail(statusDetail);
        return customerStatus;
    }

    private IdentificationDetail formPayloadForIdentificationDetail(String idType, String idNumber) {
        IdentificationDetail identificationDetail = new IdentificationDetail();
        identificationDetail.setIdNumber(idNumber);
        identificationDetail.setIdType(idType);
        return identificationDetail;
    }

    private AddressDetail formPayloadForAddressDetail(String addressType, String addressLine1, String addressLine2, String addressLine3, int pincode, String city, String state, String country, String district) {
        AddressDetail addressDetail = new AddressDetail();
        addressDetail.setAddressType(addressType);
        addressDetail.setAddressLine1(addressLine1);
        addressDetail.setAddressLine2(addressLine2);
        addressDetail.setAddressLine3(addressLine3);
        addressDetail.setPinCode(pincode);
        addressDetail.setCity(city);
        addressDetail.setState(state);
        addressDetail.setCountry(country);
        addressDetail.setDistrict(district);
        return addressDetail;
    }

    private void setHeadersAsXml(AbstractHttpMessage entity) {
        entity.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_XML);
    }

    @Trace(dispatcher = true)
    private String doPostCkycReverseUpload(String userId, String request, String endPoint, int retryCount, String context, String tssApi) throws CkycException {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(trackwizzConfig.getBaseUrl() + endPoint);
        setEntity(post, request);
        setHeaders(post);
        post.setConfig(requestConfig);
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endTime = 0;
        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post)){
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            log.info("[TSS] Response from trackwizz : {} with status : {}", response, response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            NewRelic.addCustomParameter(tssApi+HYPHEN+STATUS, String.valueOf(status));
            NewRelic.addCustomParameter(tssApi+LATENCY, (endTime - startTime)/1000);
            if(status == 200){
                log.info("[TSS] Successfully received response from trackwizz service for integration of the " + tssApi);
                return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            } else{
                log.info("Exception occured while integrating the " + tssApi);
                throw new Exception();
            }
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException | ConnectTimeoutException ex) {
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            NewRelic.addCustomParameter(tssApi+HYPHEN+STATUS, "408");
            NewRelic.addCustomParameter(tssApi+LATENCY, (endTime - startTime)/1000);
            if(retryCount < trackwizzConfig.getMaxRetryCount()){
                log.info("[TSS]Error while receiving response from trackwizz service. Failed by timeout exception, retryCount : {}", retryCount);
                return doPostCkycReverseUpload(userId, request, endPoint, retryCount+1, context, tssApi);
            }
            log.info("[TSS]Error while receiving response from trackwizz service. Failed by timeout exception, retryCount : {}", retryCount);
            throw new CkycException(ErrorCode.unknown_error, "Error while receiving response from trackwizz service. Failed by timeout exception, retry count:" + retryCount);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            NewRelic.addCustomParameter(tssApi+HYPHEN+STATUS, "NA");
            log.error("[TSS]Exception : {} for request : {}", e.getMessage(), request);
            throw new CkycException(ErrorCode.unknown_error, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

XMLUtil class where I am performing unmarshalling:

```
package com.olacabs.money.utils;


import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;


@Slf4j
public class XMLUtil {

    public static String toXML(Object data) {
        String xml = "";
        try {
            log.info("Generating xml for: " + data.getClass());
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(data.getClass());
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(data, sw);
            xml = sw.toString();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            log.error("Exception {} while converting data to xml", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return xml;
    }

}
```

Response I am getting from the class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<A63CustomerResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ApiToken>ecef5041-a08a-43c9-9599-fc2d0c8da616</ApiToken>
  <RequestId>b9393295-cf97-49c4-8c0f-978e68b1dd2e</RequestId>
  <RequestStatus>RejectedByTW</RequestStatus>
  <RequestRejectionCode>RC184</RequestRejectionCode>
  <RequestRejectionDescription>Invalid API Token, API token does not exist in TrackWizz.</RequestRejectionDescription>
  <ParentCompany>NFPL</ParentCompany>
  <CustomerResponseDetails />
</A63CustomerResponse>
```

The api token which I am passing in both the cases are same only.

Maven dependency added:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

Not posting the sample request body as it's huge.

Comment: Have you checked whether the body of the manual request, is the same with that in java after marshalling? The request's `Content-Type` is set to plain text, do you set that in your code also? There is too much code in your question, try to be more specific please.

Comment: Hi @Renis1235 yes Content-Type is same in both of the cases also about the body I copied it from java code only and tried to run in the postman. Can you tell if the jaxb dependency is correct or not?